# what is the difference between overloading an operator inside or outside a class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

In C++, i know there are two ways to overload. We can overload it inside (like class `a`) or outside (like class `b`). But, the question is, is there any difference between these two either in compile time or runtime or not?

```
class a
{
public:
    int x;
    a operator+(a p) // operator is overloaded inside class
    {
        a temp;
        temp.x = x;
        temp.x = p.x;
        return temp;
    }
};

class b
{
public:
    friend b operator+(b, b);
    int x;
};

b operator+(b p1, b p2) // operator is overloaded outside class
{
    p1.x += p2.x;
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [operator overloading(friend and member function)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770745/operator-overloadingfriend-and-member-function)

Comment: Outside the scope of the question: But both addition operators are incorrectly implemented. Operators should be overloaded to behave as expected. Normally (apart from += etc) operators do not modify there parameters (so pass by const reference and the member operator should be const.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The member `operator+` requires the LHS to be an `a` - The free operator requires LHS *or* RHS to be a `b` and the other side to be convertible to `b`

```
struct Foo {
    Foo() {}
    Foo(int) {}
    Foo operator+(Foo const & R) { return Foo(); }
};


struct Bar {
    Bar() {}
    Bar(int) {}
};

Bar operator+(Bar const & L, Bar const & R) {
    return Bar();
}


int main() {
    Foo f;
    f+1;  // Will work - the int converts to Foo
    1+f;  // Won't work - no matching operator
    Bar b;
    b+1;  // Will work - the int converts to Bar
    1+b;  // Will work, the int converts to a Bar for use in operator+

}
```

Comment: This seemingly indicates that overloading an operator outside the class is always better. But is that so?